# Why do electrons eject only if the frequency of incident ray is greater than the threshold frequency?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

Why do the electrons start moving even if the dim light (less intense) of a specific frequency falls on the material ?

Comment: Have you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect ?  Especially the part about the work function?

Comment: I have read the part and I couldn't realize why it is so ?

Comment: It is experimental fact. Scientific models like light being composed of photons can help us make sense of it. Looking up "photons" may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the light is absorbed mostly as single photons. Two-photon absorption is also possible, but it is a much rarer event.

A single photon carries energy $\hbar\omega$. If it is not sufficient to "lift" the electron to higher allowed energy, such a photon is scattered elastically, without absorption.

The problem is that the electron is not alone, it is attracted to the nucleus. And it is not a classical particle, but a standing wave. Standing waves have distinct frequencies( energies). Thus, there is an energy threshold for promoting an electron to higher levels.

Comment: Dim light means less intensity. the energy is given to a large area. Then how can an electron be ejected ?

Comment: @Vinayak: your statement *the energy is given to a large area* is not true. The whole point of the experiment is that light is exchanged between the EM wave and the metal in quanta. Quanta called "photons". The exchange of energy is localised, and a low intensity just means fewer photons per second.

Comment: similar to http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94369/why-photon-electron-energy-transfer-cant-occur-in-steps-or-does-it?rq=1 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/73471/in-famous-einsteins-photoelectric-effect-why-does-intensity-of-light-doesnt-ra?lq=1 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68147/can-the-photoelectric-effect-be-explained-without-photons

Comment: @JohnRennie Intensity is given by energy incident per area per second...am i right ?

Comment: @Vinayak: It is right when the energy has a well defined continuous energy density and flux. In case of quantum effects, one has to keep in mind that the energy flux is due to flux of photons, particles, if you like.

Comment: So how can low intense light eject an electron ? could you please explain more ?

Comment: @Vinayak: One photon carries enough energy to eject one electron. One photon is a very low intense light.

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski When this is allowed to fall on a large surface, wont they spread to other electrons

Comment: @Vinayak: No, they fall as particles, as droplets in a shower.

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski I couldnt get you. Then how is intensity related with area...I need more clarification on the packets of energy and their intensity

Comment: @Vinayak: The classical intensity is a continuous quantity. The continuity is a good thing for hight flux of individual particles. When the intensity gets low, it becomes discrete. In QM it is the probability to find a discrete particle on the area who is continuous, but particles fall one by one in uncorrelated order. Just as a heavy rain and a little rain. For the heavy rain the notion if intensity makes sense, but not for a little rain.