# Why is energy proportional to light's frequency?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, electromagnetic-radiation

I can appreciate that light can be quantised into photons, but I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding Planck's formula $$E=hf$$

Perhaps I am lacking intuition, but I don't really see why higher frequency must relate with higher energy. I can understand that higher amplitude would correlate with higher energy, but how can you explain why higher frequencies relate to higher energy?

Comment: Hi John. Can you clarify what you are asking? As you say, higher amplitude does mean higher energy density (higher intensity) but that just means you have more photons present. It's the energy of each individual photon that depends on the frequency.

Comment: @JohnRennie Hi, I'm asking why the frequency of an individual photon will change the energy it has.

Comment: @JohnHon in that case your question is a duplicate of [Does a single photon's energy depend on frequency?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/218560/does-a-single-photons-energy-depend-on-frequency-photoelectric-effect). Have you had a look at that question? In particular see [Daniel Sank's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/218563/1325).

Comment: @JohnRennie Yeah I've had a look at the answers, but they generally were to the tune of "its experimental fact" - whilst that's correct, I was hoping for an explanation with more physical reasoning (because of X, the frequency affects energy)? I guess if there's no way to explain it, then I could close

Comment: @JohnHon consider a pendulum. To increase its frequency you have to make it move faster, and that means the bob will have a greater kinetic energy. So greater frequency will mean more energy (for a constant amplitude). The photon has an oscillating electric field and the same sort of argument applies. To make the electric field of the photon oscillate faster takes more energy so the photon energy increases with frequency. This is what Daniel Sank's answer says, though he says it mathematically.

Comment: Given how energy is associated with “motion”, it seems reasonably intuitive that something oscillating quickly would have more energy than something oscillating slowly. (Typed at the same time as John Rennie’s similar comment,)

Comment: The relation between the frequency and the energy content of photons comes from observations that different subatomic particles lose different amount of energy during accelerating processes ([Bremsstrahlung](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung) for example) and it was concluded that the harder radiation (X-rays for example) has to have more energy. With the low energy of infrared you may disturb electrons, with gamma radiation you disturb also the nucleus.