# Relationship between intensity and electron emission from a metal?

Tags: visible-light, interference, photoelectric-effect, photon-emission, intensity

Here's the question: 
A xenon arc lamp is covered with an interference filter that only transmits light of 400-
nm wavelength. When the transmitted light strikes a metal surface, a stream of electrons
emerges from the metal. If the intensity of the light striking the surface is doubled,
A. more electrons are emitted in a given time interval.
B. the electrons that are emitted are more energetic.
C. both of the above.
D. neither of the above.

The answer is A, but why? Could someone explain this to me or provide an equation that would demonstrate why A is true?

Comment: Double: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/73471/in-the-famous-einsteins-photoelectric-effect-why-does-the-intensity-of-light-n?rq=1

Comment: is this a homework problem?

Comment: @nielsnielsen , it's a problem from a practice final exam. the solutions only tell you the correct answer (no explanation), and i'm confused on this one.

Comment: each photon knocks loose one electron when it hits the metal. more intensity means more photons per second which means more electrons per second being released from the metal surface. I ask about homework because the community here is pretty strict when it comes to not encouraging people to post homework questions here.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple. What is intensity? Number of photons falling on a surface per unit time per unit area. This means you are supplying more number of photons. Each photon gives one emission of  one electron -- then more number of photons will give emission of more number of electron

Answer (score 0):

Light consists of photons. Each photon kicks exactly one electron out of the metal*. By increasing the intensity more photons are sent into the metal and so more electrons are emitted, all with the same or similar kinetic energy.

*For some photons no electron is emitted, if the photon be reflected at the surface or absorbed without causing emission.

Answer (score 0):

If 400 nm wavelength is enough to cause the photoelectric effect in that particular kind of metal, then increasing the intensity will increase the number of ejected electrons but will not increase their energy. The answer is A. Increasing the energy of the photons will produce electrons with more kinetic energy.

Answer (score 0):

See the elections emitted are called PHOTOELECTRONS in this case. It is an experimental evidence that no matter what is the frequency of the light used the photoelecrtons is directly proportional to the intensity of the light and the relationship between them is linear. Like y=x so if you increase the intensity then only you can get more elections coming out